# How to add request header connection parameters safely on the clientside?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-browser, browser

It seems, that request header can only be unsafely set on the clientside.

```
     var oRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
     oRequest.setRequestHeader('Connection','Keep-Alive');
     oRequest.setRequestHeader('Keep-Alive',300);
```

ChromeVersion 31.0.1650.63 told me, that:

Refused to set unsafe header "Connection" ..

That means, i can not reuse the connection set up by the browser.
So, is it possible to add request header connection parameters safely on the clientside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, You can't, browser prohibits this, if You open Network dev tools tab , You will see that 'Connection' header is sent even if you don't set it in your `XMLHttpRequest`